# Software for analytical and computational physics with a DSP nuance

Tags: gratis, open-source, data-analysis, scientific-computing, signal-processing

What software can I use for:

- compute complex formulas which result could be not analytical, thus requiring iteration methods and substantial computational cost (ex. quantum mechanics analysis)
- easily manipulate formulas symbolically: differentials, integrals, summations and complex analysis *smooth as silk*
- thorough graphical and plotting functionalities
- data and statistical analysis and simulation (like Montecarlo's etc)

And these are the priorities. Hopefully requested a software that uses a language that allows me to produce **simple** scripts for:

- capture numerical information from source
- send controls signal to actuators or electronic systems

all limited to the source's inputs and outputs and not bothering about the device system itself.

Pure mathematics like graph theory, topology etc, not needed except combinatorics.

"Meta" requirements:

- free
- open source
- thorough wiki or forums
- programming language generally well accepted in science and engineering fields

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no one software package that does all the things that you require, at least not without a lot of work from your end. Industry standard for computational physics is going to be Ansys. Educational-standard would be something like Comsol Multiphysics. If it's more Antenna-modelling-related, then FEKO is the way to go. But these software packages are a lot of $$$, so unless you're working for some institution or company that's funding this research, most people would probably not be able to afford these packages.

When you get to developing these types of models, especially the more complex ones, the people at the top (meaning people who e.g. work for the military calculating the EM scattering of naval vessels) would be developing their own software, and the industry-standard programming language is going to be C++, but you have to be a wizard to get to that point.

If you're just learning/prototyping, then use MATLAB. It meets all your requirements. Mathcad is also good since you can write with more "mathematical notation" -also good for prototyping numerical/iterative alogrithms like Method of Moments, FEM, FDTD, etc.

Comment: Thank you very much. I already had a go with MATLAB, however I think I will need to substitute it with Octave since it's its free counterpart. Someone says they're pretty much the same thing.

Comment: @user28667 if you're going to check Octave, maybe Scilab is also worth checking out.